# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php

My code looks like this and on my page (w-o-l.ml/login.php) it displays this message

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/u536535282/public_html/includes/config.php on line 36

---

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','mysql.hostinger.co.uk');
define('DBUSER','u536535282_evan7');
define('DBPASS','anaavcnM9t7');
define('DBNAME','u536535282_dbsql');

//application address
define('DIR','http://w-o-l.ml/');
define('SITEEMAIL','it@w-o-l.ml');

try {

    //create PDO connection
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS.");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p>'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}

//include the user class, pass in the database connection
include('classes/user.php');
include('classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
$user = new User($db);

?>
```

---

if someone could point me to what is wrong i would appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at how SO parsed your code, I would say that

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS.");
```

should be

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
```

Comment: now it says SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.hostinger.co.uk' (111 "Connection refused")

Comment: @EvanWarren That's a different problem then. One question per problem please

Comment: @Machavity  so you want me to start a completely new question ratheter than keep an existing conversation going? Ok then.

Comment: Your next problem will be solvable with question/answers that will already exist.